# redirect on home page when user write index file name in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Bellow is my site directory structure:

```
 project-folder/
          index.php
```

Now I have access project using folder name like `www.project-folder.com` and also `www.folder-name.com/index.php`

**Problem**

If some one user enter `www.folder-name.com/index.php`  in URL then redirect on  `www.project-folder.com` using `htaccess`.

How can I do this ?

Below line is I tried in `htaccess`

```
Directory Index public/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this on the htaccess file of `www.folder-name.com`

```
Redirect index.php http://www.project-folder.com/index.php
```

To not make confusion, use this kind of redirect:

```
Redirect /path/to/old/file/old.php http://www.redirectedwebsite.com/path/to/new/file/new.php
```